# Which toolchain for Raspberry Pi 3 and Qt5

Tags: raspbian, linux, cross-compilation, qt, toolchain

Which is the recommended toolchain to cross-compile Qt5.6 for Raspberry Pi 3?
I tried official tools:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

but it seems they don't support the architecture and flag required for RPi3:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -pipe -Os -mthumb
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS -std=c++1z
```

Comment: The foundation seems to go forward with ARMv7 compatibility mode on the Pi3. Note that the Pi3 AArch64 kernel is still considered experimental.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going through the same thing. You need to use the 4.9.2 compiler:

Look under arm-bcm2708 for the arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf folder.

I still haven't been able to cross-compile QT for Pi3, but I'm working on it.

My adventure can be found here:
http://forum.qt.io/topic/67942/failed-cross-compile-bad-architecture

Comment: I don't know what are the differences, but I was able to compile Qt5.6 for RPi3 using the gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian cross-compiler and the mkspec for RPi2 (without ICU). Perhaps it would work also with the arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf. I will try whenever I have some spare-time.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I've used arm-linux-gnueabihf (see http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/), and MinGW64. It worked well. Don't hesitate if you want more details

Answer (score 0):

Just change -std=c++1z to -std=c++11, and it will be recognized. Indeed version 4.9.3 is C++11 compliant.